# Show div as popup on button click

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am working asp.net .

In my application i have div in my aspx page in which there is a gridview.Now i need show this div as popup on button click.How to go with it.

**code**:

```
<div id="gvdiv">
<asp:gridview id="gvsample" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

**NOTE**:I need to show the div **gvdiv** as popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**c# Code**:

```
gvdiv.datasource=yourdatasource;
gvdiv.databind();
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "showpopup();", true);
```

**script**:

```
   function showpopup() {
    $("#popup").fadeIn('slow');
    }
```

write the c# code on a button click if u want.